# Android Studio build dependencies claiming string is not found

Tags: android, build

I'm working on updating and fixing an OTA app with Android Studio. I want to get it to build so I can test with an emulator instead of my physical device, but I can't get it to build.

Error: `Error:/media/scott/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/PureFusionOTA1/app/build/intermediates/instant-run-support/debug/dependencies/AndroidManifest.xml:2 resource string/app_version (aka com.fusion.ota:string/app_version) not found`

Manifest it's complaining about:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.fusion.ota"
      android:versionCode="19"
      android:versionName="@string/app_version"
      split="lib_dependencies_apk">
</manifest>
```

Partial actual manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.fusion.ota" android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    android:versionCode="19" android:versionName="@string/app_version">

    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="26" android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

Partial Strings.xml:

```
<!-- ATTENTION -->
<!-- DO NOT TRANSLATE THE ITEMS MARKED "translatable="false" -->

<!-- App Strings -->
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">PureFusion OTA</string>
<string name="prop_name" translatable="false">ro.ota.romname</string>
<string name="app_version" translatable="false">2.5.3</string>
```

What I have tried:

- Delete the folder and re-build
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Re-sync gradle

Extra notes

- Running Android Studio 3.0 beta 2
- If I just run make, it builds with no errors
- Building by selecting "run" generates the above error and 3 more that I'll paste below

`Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:`

```
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Can you post that part of your manifest?

Comment: @sziraqui I have edited my question per your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

1. Deleting the application from your emulator/device and rerunning it.
2. If that fails, disable instant run in the `Files > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.`

Disable it until you fix the error and can run the application, and then you can enable it.

Comment: The emulator never started properly, so there's no deleting that should be required there. I disabled the instant run option and now it builds with no errors. Now my emulator just doesn't turn on, so I'll need to figure that out next.

Comment: The emulator not turning on should be a different issue altogether. Try create a brand new one and delete the previous one in yout AVD manager. If you found this helpful leave an upvote/accept for others with a similar issue to know this may help